# Use a regex to match which is stored in a hash

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.8.7

Here is a Ruby code that explains the issue:

```
1.8.7 :018 > pattern[:key] = '554 5.7.1.*Service unavailable; Helo command .* blocked using'
 => "554 5.7.1.*Service unavailable; Helo command .* blocked using" 
1.8.7 :019 > line = '554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Helo command [abc] blocked using dbl'
 => "554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Helo command [abc] blocked using dbl" 
1.8.7 :020 > line =~ /554 5.7.1.*Service unavailable; Helo command .* blocked using/
 => 0 
1.8.7 :021 > line =~ /pattern[:key]/
 => nil 
1.8.7 :022 >
```

Regex works when using directly as a string but doesn't work when I'm using it as a value of hash.

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 is too old. Try ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a Ruby question per se, it's how to construct a regex pattern that accomplishes what you want.

In "regex-ese", `/pattern[:key]/` means:

1. Find `pattern`.
2. Following `pattern` look for one of `:`, `k`, `e` or `y`.

Ruby doesn't automatically interpolate variables in strings or regex patterns like Perl does, so, instead, we have to mark where the variable is using `#{...}` inline.

If you're only using `/pattern[:key]/` as a pattern, don't bother interpolating it into a pattern. Instead, take the direct path and let Regexp do it for you:

```
pattern[:key] = 'foo'
Regexp.new(pattern[:key])
=> /foo/
```

Which is the same result as:

```
/#{pattern[:key]}/
=> /foo/
```

but doesn't waste CPU cycles.

Another of your attempts used `.`, `[` and `]`, which are reserved characters in patterns, used to help define patterns. If you need to use such characters, you can have Ruby's `Regexp.escape` add `\` escape characters appropriately, preserving their normal/literal meaning in the string:

```
Regexp.escape('5.7.1 [abc]')
=> "5\\.7\\.1\\ \\[abc\\]"
```

which, in real life is `"5\.7\.1\ \[abc\]"` (when not being displayed in IRB)

To use that in a regex, use:

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('5.7.1 [abc]'))
=> /5\.7\.1\ \[abc\]/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
line =~ /#{pattern[:key]}/
```

or...

```
line =~  Regexp.new pattern[:key]
```

If you want to escape regex special characters...

```
line =~ /#{Regexp.quote pattern[:key]}/
```

**Edit:** Since you're new to ruby, may I suggest you do this, wherever `pattern` is defined:

```
pattern[:key] = Regexp.new '554 5.7.1.*Service unavailable; Helo command .* blocked using'
```

Then you can simple use the `Regexp` object stored in `pattern`

```
line =~ pattern[:key]
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. I'm new to Ruby so still exploring. So, I understand that I am explicitly saying to take the value of the variable in the first case.